# Python: test whether an int in a list of ints fits between two ints in a list of 2-int tuples

Tags: python, python-2.7

Context: mouse genetics, I want to count the # of mutations between two lab strains depending on whether they land within exon borders.

So far, I generated 2 lists:

`SNPs = [432, 534, 677, 788, 999]` etc ~2e7 values total

`exon_limits = [(3, 6), (42, 444), (679, 999)]` etc ~5e5 values total

I simply want to count the number of SNPs (list1) that fall within exon limits (list2). Here is my code:

```
exonic = 0
non_exonic = 0
for k, l in exon_limits:
    for j in SNPs:
        if j <= k or j >= l:
            exonic += 1
        else:
            non_exonic += 1
```

I don't know much about the limits of computer science but 2e7 * 5e5 is *probably* too much to handle, right?. Also, I attempted:

```
exonic = 0
non_exonic = 0
for k, l in exon_limits:
    for j in SNPs:
        if j <= k or j >= l:
            exonic += 1
            print exonic
        else:
            non_exonic += 1
```

To see where along the algorithm python is at, but it seems it just counts up from 0 -> over 7e6 before I interrupted the program.

Each SNP will only fit within a single tuple, so if there is a way to get the iteration to stop once it finds a hit that would speed things up. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are both lists in ascending order?

Comment: Yes, and to clarify the numbers represent genomic positions.

Comment: So you want to compare every possible combination of these two lists? For example, 432 is not between 3 and 6, 432 is between 42 and 444,  432 is not between 679 and 999, etc.

Comment: Well, using my logic I compare every possible combination but this leads to way too many comparisons, so I was wondering how to get around the problem (see: Bill Letson's answer)

Comment: Though obviously you know what you want better than anyone else, I'm a little surprised by your code.  I'd have thought you wanted the number of SNPs where they were inside any of your exon_limit tuples, but your code counts something quite different.

Comment: Yes, my code did not work at all. The 'counter' simply counted up from 0 by increments of 1 and kept going (only a subset of all SNPs lie within exons, and my counter went way above this theoretical value).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the exon limits are inclusive and can't overlap, and both lists are in ascending order:

```
exonic = 0
snp_l = len(SNPs)
exon_l = len(exon_limits)
snp_idx = 0
exon_idx = 0

while snp_idx < snp_l and exon_idx < exon_l:
    if SNPs[snp_idx] < exon_limits[exon_idx][0]:
        snp_idx += 1
    elif SNPs[snp_idx] > exon_limits[exon_idx][1]:
        exon_idx += 1
    else:
        exonic += 1
        snp_idx += 1

non_exonic = snp_l - exonic
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: There are two commands to break out of a loop. `continue` will continue with the next element immidiatly and `break` will leave the whole loop. Both work for the most inner loop only.

Also instead of looping through the list of ranges, you should use a tree like structure, that can easily find the range that would match the value.

Comment: I see, I do not think I was aware that this applied to the innermost loop only. Thank you!